# Locking a hashmap to other threads

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a concurrent Hashmap which is acting as a cache. I am happy with multiple threads reading from the cache at the same time, however if a cache is reloading (writing) to the cache I do not want threads to be able to read the cache while it is reloaded and instead  read from the backup cache.

I have been looking into the reentractLock() class but it is possible to use this to just lock  the cache, examples I have seen only seem to be locking methods.

Once the cache is locked I want other threads to read from another cache instead is there a way of stating this :

```
if (cache isLocked) 
{
 read from secondary cache  
}
else {
read from cache
}
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: ConcurentHashmap in internally synchronized so you should not ave to worry about this. as long as you are working with its new atomic mutator methods you should be fine. Whats you use case exactly that makes you fear it wont work.

Comment: The use case is: A cache reload is requested (getting data from the database) and also involves clearing the cache. If another thread then tries to read the cache during the reload no data will be returned which would cause issues in the business logic and would result in a user receiving error messages.

I assumed this issue was handled internally as you suggested, but one of my coworkers (who is much more senior and experienced) insists this is not the case.

Comment: it can be handled....

Comment: it will be handled by ConcurentHashmap though not for the whole map but sliced sections of the map. See a ConcurentHashmap uses lock coarsing and will lock parts of its underlying store when mutating actions happen. It uses a re entrant lock internally. So shile you are reloading the cache again, if the user asks for a key which is not reload yet, he will get old value while the map is populated and if he asks for a new old he will get a new one. You dont need to lock the map for it as long as the map reload part uses atomic mutation methods of ConcurentHashmap.

Comment: if you don't want the user to do anything on the map until the whole relaod operation finishes then a reentrant lock use is the right way to go though personally i think its an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReentrantLock` class contains a method `isLocked()` that return true if the lock is hold by a thread. You can use this to check whether or not a thread should use regular cache or backup cache.

```
if (reentrantLock.isLocked()) 
{
 //read from secondary cache  
}
else {
 //read from cache
}
```

So when, you need to update the cache, the reloading thread will call the method `lock()` of the `ReentrantLock` object, making all reading threads to use the backup cache. When the update is done, reloading thread will called `unlock()` , making all reading threads to use regular cache.

Comment: Thanks Ortis. So to actually lock the map would it just be a case of doing this: 

myLock.lock();

-> Logic to reload cache 

-> Complete

-> myLock.unlock();